# Transit UK visa required?

Tags: visas, uk, transit

I am Canadian Permanent Resident with an Indian passport.I have a multi entry UK business visa which is for valid for 2 years but I have not used to enter to UK as of now.I am planning to travel from Canada to India on a personal visit.My wife who is also a permanent resident and indian passport holder plus my daughter who is also a permanent resident of canada with indian passport are travelling with me.We have flight from Halifax to London and the connecting flight from London to Delhi.The London to delhi flight is after 16 hours .The date of landing in london is Dec 1st while ongoing journey flight to india is on next calendar day.My question is that would we all require UK visa  for transit or since I do have business visa,I do not require visa.Also my son who is a canadian passport is travelling with us.I understand for him we do not need visa.

Comment: From the suggested duplicate question, you can learn that you should not need a transit visa if "you have a residence permit issued by Canada issued after 28 June 2002."  However, it's a good idea to follow the links in the answer and make a fresh check of the requirements, which may have changed.

Comment: No, both a UK visa and a Canadian permanent resident card are enough for transiting the UK. Doesn't matter that you haven't used the UK visa yet. So you do **not** need a new visa